# VBA error 1004 Selecting range of worksheet fails

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a part of my sheet to another sheet when in column "M" an "X" has been written:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim triggercells    As Range
Dim lastrow         As Long
    
Set triggercells = Range("M1:M100")

If Not Application.Intersect(triggercells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
           
    If Target.Value = "X" Or Target.Value = "x" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Offen").Range(Cells(Target.Row, 1), Cells(Target.Row, 13)).Select ' select part of changed row
        Selection.Copy
        
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Erledigt").Visible = True 'unhide sheet
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Erledigt").Select

            lastrow = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Erledigt").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) + 1 'get last emty row
```

but throws me out here:

```
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Erledigt").Range(Cells(lastrow, 1), Cells(lastrow, 13)).Select ' select part of row to paste to
                Selection.Paste
                
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Offen").Select 'select sheet
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Erledigt").Visible = False 'hide sheet
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
    End If
    
End If

End Sub
```

with said runtime error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `Cells(lastrow, 1)` does not take as parent the ActiveSheet "Erledigt", but the worksheet, in which the event code resides. So the `Range` and the `Cells` have different parents... To have the same parent worksheet, it should be indicated explicitly, by rewriting this part:
`Range(Cells(lastrow, 1), Cells(lastrow, 13)).Select`

to this:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Erledigt")
    .Range(.Cells(lastrow, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 13)).Select
End With
```

In general, it is a good idea to [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), but this is the next level.

Comment: I try to clean up my code when i am done and delete selects where i can, because of reasons of performance.. I am somehwat comfortable with programming in general (I am getting where i want to get to usually, like some Minecraft mod i've written in the past), but I feel like Excel's VBA is a bit "less straight forward" then java.(though not hard)

Comment: Oh also, do you need to "unhide" sheets to work with the contained cells?

Comment: @LeonS - VBA is really a bit of its own kingdom, not fair to compare it with java. And for the second question - the answer is "no", but the good thing is that you could have tested it for less time than writing the comment. Keep on trying testing stuff, the macro recorder is something that Java does not have :)

Comment: Well i found this while researching if you can or not: https://excelribbon.tips.net/T009329_Running_Macros_on_Hidden_Worksheets.html